# BootstrapVue Button States: Reset button when other button is clicked

Tags: vuejs2, toggle, show-hide, bootstrap-vue

Consider following code

```html
<div id='app'>
  <div class="card shadow bg-light m-4">
    <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields" responsive>
      <template #cell(age)="data">
        <b-button :pressed.sync="data.item.age_visible" pill variant="outline-danger">
          <span v-if="data.item.age_visible">{{data.item.age}}</span>
          <span v-else>Show Age</span>
        </b-button>
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      fields: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age'],
      items: [
        { age: 40, age_visible: false, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
        { age: 21, age_visible: false, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
        { age: 89, age_visible: false, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
        { age: 38, age_visible: false, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
      ]
    }
  },
});
```

which gives you

[image]

When you click on "Show Age", the age is revealed. Try it on [codepen](https://codepen.io/Hotschke/pen/jOyBoNG).

**My question:**

When someone clicks in a different row on "Show Age", the age in the revealed row should now be hidden again. How can I achieve this?

Also let me know whether the column `age_visible` is actually necessary.

Versions

- Vue 2.6.12
- Bootstrap 4.6.0
- BootstrapVue 2.21.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `age_visible` is necessary. What the issue seems to be here is that you never do anything to a button that was clicked on before once you move to the next one. When you click on a new button, the last button should be back to its original state.

My idea was to have something that keeps track of the current index in `data()` and then when you click on a button, it checks if the current index matches the button that was just clicked. If true, then it shows the age and if false then it hides it. The only weird CSS thing about my solution is that the button no longer stays red once it's clicked on unless you hover over it.

Here's what I have

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      currentIndex: -1,
      fields: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age'],
      items: [
        { index: 0, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
        { index: 1, age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
        { index: 2, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
        { index: 3, age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setIndex(pendingIndex) {
      this.currentIndex = pendingIndex
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <div class="card shadow bg-light m-4">
    <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields" responsive>
      <template #cell(age)="data">
        <b-button @click="setIndex(data.item.index)" pill variant="outline-danger">
          <span v-if="currentIndex === data.item.index">{{data.item.age}}</span>
          <span v-else>Show Age</span>
        </b-button>
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</div>
```